# Colored, numbered, paged git diff

Tags: command-line

The default behaviour of `git diff` — syntax-colored, paged — is very nice to work with, but it would be slightly nicer with line numbers for context, particularly for larger diffs, and especially for the final page.

```
git diff | nl | more
```

almost gives me everything I need, but it discards the coloring; any way I can get that back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `less -r` to display the colour, but you will need to force `git` to use colours because when you pipe `git diff` it will difault to `--nocolor`

```
git diff --color HEAD~3 HEAD | nl | less -R
```

If you like to get the line numbers per line, try looking about the solutions suggested here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455377/git-diff-with-line-numbers-git-log-with-line-numbers

Comment: Using `less -R` outputs only ANSI "color" escape sequences in "raw" form.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of piping `git log`, you can use `less`'s built in line-numbering. Typing **-N** in `less` will cause it to display line numbers.

Comment: I always forget quite how configurable git is. This lets me set the pager options globally and I don't have to manually pipe anything anymore. Thanks; I've added the full command I used in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dylan Frese's answer got me investigating a bit, and I believe this solution to be slightly better than the one I previously accepted; for my purposes, anyway.

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager 'less -NR'
```

This then lets me `git diff` and not even have to think about it. Of course, there are occasions where you might not want this to be a permanent, global change, so the info. here is all still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use command:
`git diff --color=always | less -RN`

And could define a shortcut command in `~/.bashrc`:

`alias gdc='git diff --color=always | less -RN'`

Answer (score 0):

> but it would be slightly nicer with line numbers for context,

I wrote `git diffn` which does this. Sample output is in the screenshot below, showing that it works with colors too.

Full installation instructions in my other answer here: [Stack Overflow: Git diff with line numbers (Git log with line numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61997003/4561887). Installation is easy--just a few commands.

As a wrapper around `git diff`, it supports all options and arguments that `git diff` does.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try [showlinenum](https://github.com/jay/showlinenum) and pipe it to `less -R`, e.g.

```
git diff --color=always | showlinenum.awk | less -R
```

[image]

About showlinenum, just clone the github repo and copy `showlinenum.awk` to `PATH`. The script will give you exact line number.

Also you may want to use `git difftool`. If you're comfortable with `less`, then `vimdiff` (`git difftool -t vimdiff`) is a nice idea:

[image]

Read `man git-difftool` for more.

Comment: showlinenum.awk is a script that you have on your local machine?

Comment: No it's available on Github. Sorry I didn't make the link clear.